# Velocity Template debugging and Catch exceptions

Tags: java, velocity

How to print the exact line no of exception in Velocity Template at runtime?

I am using Veloeclipse for development to validate syntax related problems.. This works, but for Runtime based Exceptions information is missing.

I am sending a logging object to context of VT so when I want to log something I use the `$logging.log(contenttobelogged)`

If some exception occurs during runtime, the exception trace does not contain any line numer details of Velocity template.

For that I have to put my log for each lines , so log makes code nasty. Can you  guide me to log errors with proper line number?

**Exception Trace :**

```
Template Name @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ yes/po/POSSellerRSPGridData_JSON.vm
org.apache.velocity.exception.MethodInvocationException: Invocation of method 'get' in  class java.util.ArrayList threw exception class java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException : Index: 1, Size: 1
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTMethod.execute(ASTMethod.java:308)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTReference.execute(ASTReference.java:202)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTReference.value(ASTReference.java:345)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTSetDirective.render(ASTSetDirective.java:135)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTBlock.render(ASTBlock.java:94)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTIfStatement.render(ASTIfStatement.java:109)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTBlock.render(ASTBlock.java:94)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Foreach.render(Foreach.java:344)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTDirective.render(ASTDirective.java:153)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTBlock.render(ASTBlock.java:94)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Foreach.render(Foreach.java:344)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTDirective.render(ASTDirective.java:153)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.SimpleNode.render(SimpleNode.java:271)
    at org.apache.velocity.Template.merge(Template.java:296)
    at ecnet.rd.core.template.TemplateResolver.merge(TemplateResolver.java:81)
    at ecnet.rd.helper.YES_PO_Helper.mergerTemplateDetails(YES_PO_Helper.java:166)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Velocity tools 3.0](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/#whats-new-in-30) have a new tool, [LogTool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/LogTool.html) enable you to **log error message inside template** with [error](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/LogTool.html#error(java.lang.String)) method